# Insert a Sequence for every query execution in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have an automated job that runs an sql query. Below is the query.

```
Insert into employee_master (Job_Run_ID, Employee_ID, Employee_Name, Employee_Location) values (runId, eId, eName, eLoc);
```

Let's say this job runs for the first time and it inserts 10 records. Now, All the inserted records should have Job_Run_Id as 10001.

For the second run, the Job_Run_Id should increment, and 10002 should be the Job_Run_Id for all records inserted into the table.

Is it possible.? Please give your inputs.

Comment: I think your data structure is in trouble here. What is the primary key of this table?

Comment: The Oracle way prior 12c is to populate the id in a trigger from a sequence. Everything else is likely wrong. YMMV, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do this several ways. First, you could create a sequence and select the next number from that before running your batch. The next would be to simply:

```
SELECT Max(Job_Run_ID) + 1 INTO New_Job_ID FROM employee_master;
```

Then do your job loop running your inserts:

```
INSERT INTO employee_master (New_Job_ID, Employee_ID, Employee_Name, Employee_Location) 
VALUES (runId, eId, eName, eLoc);
```

Comment: Why not use a sequence here? If another job starts while one is running, both would get the same max(job_run_id).

Comment: Yes, I did mention Sequences. I did not go in-depth because someone else had already mentioned sequences, but apparently deleted their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a sequence to ensure each job run gets a unique value. Use PL/SQL to re-use the same value for all rows inserted in a job run, e.g.:

```
<<p>>
DECLARE
  job_run_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
  job_run_id := job_run_seq.NEXTVAL;
  INSERT INTO employee_master (job_run_id, ...)
  VALUES (p.job_run_id, ...);
END p;
```